When Does a Singularity Become Naked in Space-Time?
A singularity within a space-time  is typically hidden behind an event horizon, preventing any information from the singularity from reaching distant observers. However, a singularity may be "naked" if it is not enclosed by an event horizon, allowing signals from the singularity to reach the conformal boundary ∂, representing infinity.
Consider a singularity associated with a Terminal Indecomposable Past(TIP), which captures the causal past of the singularity. The conformal boundary ∂ of the space-time compactifies infinity.
when the singularity is naked, meaning it can influence distant regions of space-time and potentially be observed by an observer at infinity, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the inclusion:
Under what circumstances does the TIP of the singularity intersect the causal past of ∂, leading to the formation of a naked singularity?

I think the first condition is that there be a physical scenario where a singularity can be naked in the first place, which is generally not considered to be possible since an observer being able to interact with a singularity is problematic to say the least. For example a naked Kerr or Kerr-Newman singularity constitutes a time machine since there are closed timelike curves found around the event horizon ordinarily hidden by the event horizon.

It is counterintuitive though, I don't know the physical law preventing CTCs.

In your question, TIP is a fancy wording for the horizon. With this, your question boils down to, “under what conditions does the horizon stop being a horizon?” Well, never, since the horizon itself is located at the eternity of the coordinate time. Thus your question is contradictory and not well defined. Also, the “naked” singularity you are asking about is timelike, but a singularity behind a single horizon is spacelike. You cannot make a spacelike singularity timelike, you must (hypothetically) create one from scratch.

Is singularity behind a single. horizon always spacelike?

@Lagrangiann Hypothetically, probably not. If you smuggle enough negative mass through the horizon of a supermassive black hole and then make it collapse into a small black hole there, it might form a naked timelike singularity inside the horizon. However the main known singularities there (like Schwarzschild or Oppenheimer-Snyder) are spacelike.
